# Оставить в строке только первую букву

Tags: вёрстка, css

Можно ли на голом CSS решить поставленную задачу? Предположительный вариант был:

```
strong::first-letter { display:inline; }
strong { display:none; }
```

Но он не сработал. Это вообще можно провернуть в чистом виде?

**Обновление**

Есть текст, оформленный в цветной продольной рамочке. Надо средствами голого CSS оставить вместо прямоугольника с текстом маленький кружочек с первой буквой этого самого текста. Круг из прямоугольника сделать — не вопрос, а вот от текста одну букву оставить...

Варианты типа «обработать яваскриптом» или «повлиять на вывод» не рассматриваются.

Можно рассмотреть вариант — оставить вместо строчки UTF-8 символ. Но опять же, на CSS, не трогая вёрстку, так разве можно?

Comment: А задача то какая)?

Comment: strong {
width:10px;
letter-spacing:5px;
overflow:hidden
}

мб как-то так?

Т.е., раздвигаем буквы, и показываем только первые Н пиксилей чтобы влезла первая буква. остальное - скрываем.

Comment: @Crus, круга не будет в вашем варианте

Comment: Чтобы было яснее, моя структура:
<div class1><h3 class2><em class3><strong></all>
Текст — в strong. Круг из прямоугольника — в em. Они не в одном месте.

Comment: @lopar, посмотрите мой вариант, кривота, конечно, жуткая, но результат есть. :)

Comment: Я пытался натолкнуть на идею, а не написать рабочий код ^_~

Круто, если получилось.)

Comment: @MasterAlex, к сожалению, не мой вариант, так как не могу влиять на вёрстку.

Comment: @lopar, а зачем на неё слиять? http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/nbk4p69e/3/
делаете селектор по нужному классу у дива и всё будет работать

Comment: @MasterAlex, ибо если между ними внезапно воткнётся любой текст — всё слетит. Решил вопрос совсем кардинально: http://jsfiddle.net/vzzwey5d/. Понятно, что не соотетствует условию вопроса, но из многих адекватных решений это пока кажется самым ровным.

Comment: а что насчет такой идеи?

    h3
      color: transparent
    h3:first-letter
      color: white

и не надо никаких overflow (хотя с width поработать придется) ![](http://www.ocreef.com/images/emoticons/white/crazy.gif)

Comment: @Crus, спасибо. Вы c @MasterAlex таки натолкнули. :)

Comment: @Etki, или я что-то делаю не так или телега не едет. http://jsfiddle.net/3zc6htsg/

Comment: @Etki, кстати да, я замаскировал текст под цвет background, а его ведь можно сделать просто прозрачным :) @lopar, возьмите мой вариант и вместо `color: #fff`, поставьте `color: transparent`, визуально ничего не изменится, но теперь не на белом фоне буквы тоже не будет видно. :) А `overflow:hidden` и в моём варианте больше для мебели, чем для обрезания чего-либо.

Comment: @lopar, потому что я написал, как привык, в sass, а не css

http://jsfiddle.net/3zc6htsg/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Псевдокласс `:first-letter` применяется только к блочным элементам, например, `p, div`, а также к элементам, у которых значение display задано как inline-block, table-caption или table-cell.
2. Допустимо использовать только свойства, относящиеся к шрифту, изменению цвета текста и фона.

UPD.

Доработал вариант [[@Crus](/users/25785/crus)](/users/25785/crus) до [работающего примера](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/nbk4p69e/1/):

```
div {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
}
div:first-letter { 
    font-size: 18px; 
    line-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 10px 17px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
}
```